# how to use a filter criteria in view?

Tags: views

I have one view which shows total number of time a particular node has been visited and few more details.
now i want to use a filter which shows most viewed node.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you facing to achieve it? Edit your question and put more info about What you did and where are you stuck ?

Comment: did you try adding "SORT CRITERIA" in the view as descending for node view count.

Answer (score 2):

Sort your view by node views descending.

Then limit your view to only show 1 row.

The remaining result will be your node with the most views.

Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a field in the **Sort Criteria** which is under filter criteria

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: -_- It does answer his question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a contextual filter to do this all at once - without having to configure both the "sort criteria" and the "pager options"

Assuming something like "content:number-of-views" is accessible as a filter option. Go to:

views>yourview>advanced>contextual-filters>add>"content:number-of-views"

You can now configure your contextual filter...

I would try :

When the filter value is NOT available

- "display a summary"
- Configure sort order  - "descending"
- Configure sort by - "number of views"
- Override number of items to display  - "1."